# Focus doesn't move to input fields in IE using Selenium Server

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium

I use Selenium Server+java.

Problem is - Focus to input field not always move in IE, FF+Chrome work fine.
Web page in dynamic.

This is my peace of code that I used to type a value to input field.
PS when selenium type a value to input field focus must be changed & other field will calculated this field with some another, that is why I need to change focus (as it will be like a click of mouse*) * mouse Down & UP I have already used - doesn't work to me.

```
public void WaitAndType(String locator, String valueToType)
            throws InterruptedException {
        long ts=System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (selenium.isElementPresent(locator) == true) {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                selenium.focus(locator);
                selenium.mouseDown(locator);
                selenium.mouseUp(locator);
                selenium.type(locator, valueToType);
                break;
            }
            else{
                Thread.sleep(200);
                }
            if(System.currentTimeMillis()-ts>10000){
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: The easiest way to change focus is to click a different element.

Comment: i send click to IE BUT in fact i see that it is happened nothing, in this scenario is not always repeated. Sometimes it work fine

Comment: i fix problem usinng "Event" like this selenium.fireEvent(locator, "blur");